# anyone help me out here why getting error in my store procedure

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

i am trying to insert all date in daterange table within specific given date rane.here is my procedure but i am getting error and i can't solve it.

```
   DELIMITER//  
   CREATE PROCEDURE example(IN sdate DATE, IN enddate DATE)  
   BEGIN  
   SET @sdate = sdate;
   SET @enddate=enddate;

   WHILE(@sdate < @enddate) DO
   INSERT INTO daterange SET day = sdate;
   sdate = DATE_ADD(sdate, INTERVAL 1 DAY);   
   END WHILE;

   SELECT * FROM daterange;

   END//;  
   DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: what error are you getting?

Comment: select statemet is not working

Answer (score 0):

Try enter space into Delimiter and //
And your while have syntax erros, look at the fix procedure:

```
DELIMITER //  
CREATE PROCEDURE example(IN sdate DATE, IN enddate DATE)  
BEGIN  

declare varDay date;

WHILE(sdate < enddate) DO

    INSERT INTO daterange ([your-column]) values (varDay);

    SET sdate = DATE_ADD(sdate, INTERVAL 1 DAY);    
    SET varDay = sdate;
END WHILE;

SELECT * FROM daterange;

END //;  
DELIMITER ;
```